# Can a function map a single X value to multiple Y values?

Tags: functions

If I have the domain X: A, B, C, and the domain Y: 1, 2, 3, 4 is it possible to have every value of Y correspond to a value in C?

For exampleC could f(x) = 1, and at the same time f(x) = 2? Is it possible for f(A) to correspond to 1 and 2?

Thanks

Comment: For a _function_, no, but for a _relation_, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a function map a single X value to multiple Y values?

By definition, no. A function maps every X value in the valid domain to only a single Y value.

> "In mathematics, a function is a relation between a set of inputs and a set of permissible outputs with the property that each input is related to **exactly one** output".

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, the definition of a function requires that any single input may only have one output.